# Catch-all phrase for IPs, domain names, and virtual directories

Tags: domain-name-system

Assume there is a page named `page.html` that is accessed on a server through HTTP and port 80.  Not counting the name of the page at all, nor the protocol or the port number, what is the general, catch-all phrase for things like this:

```
10.1.4.7
10.1.4.7/DirectoryWherePageExists
www.UserFriendlyDomainName.com
example.UserFriendlyDomainName.net.ca
UserFriendlyDomainName.net/SomeDirectory/AndAnother/DirectoryWherePageExists
```

(I wanted to tag this with something like "terminology", but nothing like that seems to be available.)

---

For instance, suppose there's an XML element that has different bits of information separated out that can be used to get the URL of a couple of asmx pages for some web services:

```
<WebService>
    <Protocol>HTTP</Protocol>
    <IPAddress>10.1.4.7</IPAddress>
    <Port>80</Port>
    <MainServiceName>Service1</MainServiceName>
    <SecondaryServiceName>Service2</SecondaryServiceName>
    <!-- Optional element <SubdirectoryPath>folder1/folder2 ...</SubDirectoryPath> -->
</WebService>
```

So the URL in this case would be `http://10.1.4.7:80/Service1.asmx` for Service1 and `http://10.1.4.7:80/Service2.asmx` for Service2.  And the field `IPAddress` is appropriately named, because in this case, the value (`10.1.4.7`) actually is an IP address.

But what if you want the URLs to look like one of these:

```
1. http://www.somewebsite.com.uk:80/Service1.asmx
2. http://somewebsite.net:80/somedirectory/anothersubdirectory/services/Service1.asmx
```

Neither is an IP address.  In the second case, what I'm referring to would actually be on either side of the port number, but in the first case, you could clearly substitute `10.1.4.7` in the XML element with `www.somewebsite.com.uk`.

So especially for the first case, where you can just change the value of `IPAddress`, and that would work just fine, what would be a better name for `IPAddress`?  What is a good catch-all phrase for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of "IP address", use "Host", which can be identified by either DNS name or IP.

Everything in a URL after the host (and possibly port number) will be the path, followed possibly by queries or fragments. Doesn't look like you're accounting for anything other than path.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator